# How can I disable a javascript from running only from iPad device?

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have a website which has a widget that runs on javascript.
I want to disable that javascript only when a user comes into my website via an iPad device.

What element should I add to my javascript in order to achieve this goal ?

Note that I'm not looking for a method for the user to disable the javascript from the browser settings.
I need to disable the javascript from running only when a user comes to my website with an iPad device.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Comment: look into user-agent strings

Answer (score 1):

Check the user-agent , and make your adequate controls

### example

> return true for iPhone/iPad/iPod

```
function checkiOS(){
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
}

if(checkiOS) alert("iPad/iPhone/iPod");
```

---

**Utility**

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html
- [detectmobilebrowsers.com](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/javascript)